# ActionMailer Successful outbound email but not receiving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I looked around for similar issues but nothing seems to work for me.
I'm using [ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)
to send emails. The email outbound went through successfully but I I'm not receiving it in my email.

I have enabled [POP](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/6323470) mail service.

*config/environments/development.rb*

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   :authentication => :plain,
   :address => "smtp.mailgun.org",
   :port => 587,
   :domain => "tvtt.co",
   :user_name => "postmaster@tvtt.co",
   :password => "password"
}
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

*mailers/notification_mailer.rb*

```
class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'support@tvtt.com'

  def acquisition_email(listing)
    @neighborhood = listing.neighborhood
    @tenant_fee = listing.tenant_fee
    @listing = listing
    mail(
      to: "yseremail@gmail.com",
      subject: "List your place on tvtt!"
    )
  end

end
```

And here is the "successful" output for the email outbound:

```
Sent mail to yseremail@gmail.com (23.1ms)
Date: Sat, 12 Dec 2015 20:05:13 -0500
From: support@tvtt.com
To: yseremail@gmail.com
Message-ID: <566cc44930cf0_64f23fc8933831dc28566@yseremail-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>
Subject: List your place on tvtt!
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Comment: when did you open your mailgun account? has it been verified and approved?

Comment: yes but I was using it on another application. Is there specific config for each app ?

Comment: hmm... not sure about that.

Comment: I would use [MailCatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/) for development and setup Mailgun on your staging/production instead. Using a gmail/pop3 account in development has tons of portability headaches if you are several developers on a project. The additional plusses are that there is no delay and it caches everything going out so you don't have to use your own email for demo accounts.